# How to fix Failed to compile virtual memory to PCH?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, precompiled-headers

This pic really tortured me these past few days.

i created a pretty small lib myself. only 400 kb and use as library function.

Create new project and reference to it as well as using the header file. but after compiling I get this error:

[image]

How to fix this? this not work for me:

[image]

Comment: Hi @drescherjm, this error occurs sporadically, after about 30 builds it reappears once. set 1000 is quite a shock to me as I have never needed to set up a ZM. a few days ago it appeared and I tried the ZM100. Do I need to clean up somewhere?

Comment: Hi, @drescherjm Ok, I will try to clean it regularly.  hope it goes away !

Answer (score 1):

According to the Doc；[Compiler Error C3859](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3859?view=msvc-160)

> Starting in Visual Studio 2015, the /Zm recommendation is only
> significant when using the #pragma hdrstop directive. In other cases,
> it's a spurious error that indicates Windows virtual memory pressure
> issues.
>
> If your precompiled header uses a #pragma hdrstop directive, use the
> /Zm compiler flag to specify a larger value for the precompiled header
> file. Otherwise, consider reducing the number of parallel compilation
> processes in your build.

Could you please tell us which version of visual studio are you using? One of the best things you can do if you’re experiencing errors with PCH files is to move to a newer Visual C++ compiler. We have fixed many PCH memory pressure bugs in VS 2015 and VS 2017.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the link:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/precompiled-header-pch-issues-and-recommendations/

Comment: Hi, I am using vs2019-version16.8.5. My project is setup c++17-platform v141. I'm not sure where this virtual memory is coming from? In my library declare many functions and classes using dllexport. is it it?. this error just appeared recently.